# Kendo Autocomplete style goes crazy after being populated

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I am running into a weird issue with a Kendo AutoComplete widget.. The set up is as follows

I have a kendo dropdownlist being populated on document.ready and throwing a zero value to a function for populating a kendo autocomplete widget, on the change event of the LoadStates function, it calls the LoadCounty function and passes the selected id and then the autocomplete loads, but it goes all crazy.

Here is how it looks on the document.ready

[image: On document.ready]

and here is how it loosk once I select a state
[image: After state selection]

And without further ado, here is the code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.913/styles/kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.913/styles/kendo.blueopal.min.css">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.913/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input id="txtState" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- End txtState -->

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input id="txtCounty" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- End txtState -->

    </div>
    <!-- End form horizontal -->
  </div>


  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var stateData = [{
          "StateID": 1,
          "StateName": "Oklahoma"
        },
        {
          "StateID": 2,
          "StateName": "Texas"
        }
      ];

      LoadStates(stateData);
      LoadCounty(0);
    });

    function LoadStates(stateData) {
      var countyData1 = [{
          "CountyID": 1,
          "CountyName": "CountyA"
        },
        {
          "CountyID": 2,
          "CountyName": "CountyB"
        },
        {
          "CountyID": 3,
          "CountyName": "CountyC"
        },
        {
          "CountyID": 4,
          "CountyName": "CountyD"
        }
      ];

      var countyData2 = [{
          "CountyID": 5,
          "CountyName": "CountyE"
        },
        {
          "CountyID": 6,
          "CountyName": "CountyF"
        },
        {
          "CountyID": 7,
          "CountyName": "CountyG"
        },
        {
          "CountyID": 8,
          "CountyName": "CountyH"
        }
      ];

      $("#txtState").kendoDropDownList({
        dataSource: stateData,
        index: 0,
        dataTextField: "StateName",
        dataValueField: "StateID",
        animation: false,
        optionLabel: "State",
        change: function(e) {
          var dataItem = e.sender.dataItem();
          if (dataItem.StateID === 1) {
            LoadCounty(countyData1);
          } else {
            LoadCounty(countyData2);
          }

        }
      });
    }

    function LoadCounty(countyData) {
      $("#txtCounty").kendoAutoComplete({
        dataSource: countyData,
        dataTextField: "CountyName",
        dataValueField: "CountyID",
        filter: "startswith",
        placeholder: "Type County...",
        select: function(e) {
          var DataItem = this.dataItem(e.item.index());
          currentSelectedItem = DataItem.CountyID;
        }
      });
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kendo isn't smart enough to re-initialize a widget, so you can't init a widget over an existing one. You have to [`destroy`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/autocomplete#methods-destroy) it and clear it's remaining DOM(yep, it leaves trashy elements behind). I suggest you to create a template with the target element - `txtCounty` in this case - and recreate it everytime you need to refresh the auto complete widget:

```
function LoadCounty(countyData) {
    var $acEl = $("#txtCounty"),
        $container = $("#county-container");

    if ($acEl.data("kendoAutoComplete")) {
        // Destroys the widget
        $acEl.data("kendoAutoComplete").destroy();

        // Clears the container
        $container.empty();
    }

    // Get the template and append to the container
    var template = kendo.template($("#county-template").html());
    $container.html(template({}));

    $("#txtCounty").kendoAutoComplete({
        dataSource: countyData,
        dataTextField: "CountyName",
        dataValueField: "CountyID",
        filter: "startswith",
        placeholder: "Type County...",
        select: function(e) {
          var DataItem = this.dataItem(e.item.index());
          currentSelectedItem = DataItem.CountyID;
        }
    });
}
```

And the template:

```
<script id="county-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <input id="txtCounty" />
</script>
```

I know it sucks but that's the way kendo goes. Below your code updated:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.913/styles/kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.913/styles/kendo.blueopal.min.css">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.913/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
  <script id="county-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <input id="txtCounty" />
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input id="txtState" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- End txtState -->

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <div class="form-group" id="county-container">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- End txtState -->

    </div>
    <!-- End form horizontal -->
  </div>


  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var stateData = [{
          "StateID": 1,
          "StateName": "Oklahoma"
        },
        {
          "StateID": 2,
          "StateName": "Texas"
        }
      ];

      LoadStates(stateData);
      LoadCounty(0);
    });

    function LoadStates(stateData) {
      var countyData1 = [{
          "CountyID": 1,
          "CountyName": "CountyA"
        },
        {
          "CountyID": 2,
          "CountyName": "CountyB"
        },
        {
          "CountyID": 3,
          "CountyName": "CountyC"
        },
        {
          "CountyID": 4,
          "CountyName": "CountyD"
        }
      ];

      var countyData2 = [{
          "CountyID": 5,
          "CountyName": "CountyE"
        },
        {
          "CountyID": 6,
          "CountyName": "CountyF"
        },
        {
          "CountyID": 7,
          "CountyName": "CountyG"
        },
        {
          "CountyID": 8,
          "CountyName": "CountyH"
        }
      ];

      $("#txtState").kendoDropDownList({
        dataSource: stateData,
        index: 0,
        dataTextField: "StateName",
        dataValueField: "StateID",
        animation: false,
        optionLabel: "State",
        change: function(e) {
          var dataItem = e.sender.dataItem();
          if (dataItem.StateID === 1) {
            LoadCounty(countyData1);
          } else {
            LoadCounty(countyData2);
          }

        }
      });
    }

    function LoadCounty(countyData) {
      var $acEl = $("#txtCounty"),
          $container = $("#county-container");
      
      if ($acEl.data("kendoAutoComplete")) {
        // Destroys the widget
        $acEl.data("kendoAutoComplete").destroy();
        
        // Clears the container
        $container.empty();
      }
      
      // Get the template and append to the container
      var template = kendo.template($("#county-template").html());
      $container.html(template({}));
    
      $("#txtCounty").kendoAutoComplete({
        dataSource: countyData,
        dataTextField: "CountyName",
        dataValueField: "CountyID",
        filter: "startswith",
        placeholder: "Type County...",
        select: function(e) {
          var DataItem = this.dataItem(e.item.index());
          currentSelectedItem = DataItem.CountyID;
        }
      });
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I hope it helps.